# Avoid closing dropdown when clicking to checked a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I use the following code to hide or show a column in a table when the user click on a checkbox in a dropdown:

JS

```
$('#columnsListDropDown :checkbox').on('change', function() {
      $("#myTable").find("[data-column='" + this.value + "']").toggle(this.checked);
      return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu columnsFilterDropDownMenu" id="columnsListDropDown">
    <li>
        <label class="small" data-value="Type">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Type" checked="true">Type</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="small" data-value="Release">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Release" checked="true">Release</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When i click on the checkbox itself, the dropdown stays opened, but when i click on the label, the dropdown is closed. In this case i would to let the dropdown opened. How can i do that ?

Comment: Please include all relevant code, like css and so on

Comment: `this.value` and `this.checked` are correct?

Comment: @ElmerDantas Yes because the code works fine when clicking on checkbox

Comment: does the `onchange` function fire when you click on the label (you can add a `console.log` inside to check it)? If not, you could add something like `$('#columnsListDropDown :label').on('click', function() { /* add code to get the checkbox linked to this label */.trigger('change'); }`

Comment: @Kaddath Yes i put a breakpoint to check and i well goes in the function when the label is clicked

Comment: if logging `value` and `checked` doesn't bring a clue on this, maybe you can try to add the same kind of function than in my previous comment, but with a `event.preventDefault()` and a manual value change for the checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by `Kaddath` in comments `event.stopPropagation` on label click should stop event bubbling and thus the dropdown should not collapse.

Sample code:

```
$('#columnsListDropDown li label').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Refer [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/ow81bt87/).